# Having Problems with "imageliteral" in swift

Tags: xcode, swift5

Im learning swift from scratch, and Im struggling with imageliteral, Xcode doesnt recognize the word, any help would be welcome

what I'm using: syntax ->  what.who = value
ex:   mainImage.image = "imageliteral"

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding two different answers that work perfectly fine. It seems that "imageliteral" doesnt work at all, but there are 2 alternatives

1. using UIImage
   ex: mainImage.image = UIImage(named: "whateverYouNeed")

2)using UIImage
ex: mainImage.image = UIImage(ImageLiteralResourceName:            "whateverYouNeed")

both works totally fine, and tried both!!!